# C# WebClient with https

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, https

I want to use https to upload a file using WebClient's UploadData method. And I want to ignore server side certificate verification (always accept server certificate and only use encryption feature of https).

I have tried hard but cannot find a similar sample. Could anyone advise me how to implement? Any reference samples?

I am using VSTS2008 + C# + .Net 3.5. Target server is running with IIS 7.0 + Windows Vista x64.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding this before you send you HTTPS requests (make sure you import `System.Net` namespace).

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, 
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
   return true;
};
```