# Using HtmlUnit on .NET for https

Tags: c#, .net, http, https, htmlunit

I have a problem in **Using HtmlUnit on .NET for Headless Browser Automation**.I am using [Steven Sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/) for this.

Now my problem is, my site is using **HTTPS** protocol and using this i am getting error of 
**unknown protocol https**. so is there any way to solve this?.

My code:

```
private WebClient webClient;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        webClient = new WebClient();
    }

    [Test]
    public void create()
    {
        // Arrange: Load the demo page
        var Page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com/"); // won't work

        var Page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com/"); //work for this

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Page.asXml());            
    }
```

any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the absence of a certificate, so try using what is descibed in this question [C# WebClient with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339250/c-sharp-webclient-with-https), it might be what you are searching for.

Good luck.