# webclient DownloadStringcreates tunnel with HTTPS

Tags: c#, https, webclient

I am trying to use the API at api.pwnedpasswords.com

It requires me to do a GET request over HTTPS

This works well using WebClients OpenRead() method, but that requires me to then deal with a streamReader.

I want to use the DownloadStringTaskAsync() method in stead, but it keeps trying to open a tunnel first, which does not work with this API so the request fails

I have tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339250/c-sharp-webclient-with-https) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536352/webclient-https-issues), but it does not fix my issue.

**Question:** How do I get WebClient.DownloadStringto issue a GET request?

**Not working - using DownloadStringTaskAsync**

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
webClient.Headers.Add("UserAgent", "Backend; PasswordChange"); 
var response = await wc.DownloadString($"https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/{prefix}");
if (response.IndexOf(hash.Substring(5), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
    return BadRequest"Password not allowed. Please choose a more secure one.");
```

**Code working - using OpenRead**

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("UserAgent", "Backend; PasswordChange");
Stream stream = wc.OpenRead($"https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/{prefix}");
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string hashList = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    var stuff = hashList.IndexOf(postfix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (hashList.IndexOf(postfix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        return BadRequest("Password not allowed. Please choose a more secure one.");
}
```

Comment: What encoding is your code using?

Comment: UTF8, I explicitly set that in both code examples.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the headers in working and non working.  Make working headers look exactly like non working.

Comment: I have used Fiddler, this is how I know DownloadString() tries to do "CONNECT api.pwnedpasswords.com:443" rather than the expected GET request

Comment: You are using DownloadString() which is doing a connect instead of a Get().  See following : https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: Did you read the question? I am confused as to why you ask these things. My problem is already outlined and none of what you ask or suggest could change or add to the solution.

Comment: You said in response that fiddler showed the code was doing a Connect instead of a Get.  The link is the http specification that shows connect and get are two different methods.  So why are you doing DownLoadString (which is a Connect) when you really want a Get()?

Comment: My question is specifically "How to use DownloadString to do a GET request".
I have stated the reason, I wish to not deal with a streamReader, the code is simply neater if I can use DownLoadString.

Comment: You cannot change DownloadString to use a GET.  It is impossible.  You may be able to add to the CONNECT method to add equivalent credentials that GET is using. I'm not an expert in the differences between Connect and Get.  I do not think all server support Connect.  Wiki may help : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel

Comment: If I use DownloadString with HTTP then a GET request will be issued. I am assuming there can be a way to change how HTTPS is handled

Comment: You are working with the NET Library.  What you say is possible and what the library allows is two different things.  You can look at the source code line 383 is the Download File and 435 is OpenRead : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,cc8549dcc9a62544